# Unresolved dependency when using iceblue spire appi

Tags: java, apache-poi, gradle-plugin, apache-poi-4, spire.doc

I want to compare two docx files and for this reason I am using Ice blue spire api which compare two documents, and checks whether the two documents are identical or not. I am using the following gradle dependency to my gradle project.It is saying unresolved dependency.

Unresolved dependency: e-iceblue:spire.doc:11.5.5

Any help would be highly appreciated

I try to add ice blue spire gradle dependency, but the following error is appearing.

Unresolved dependency: e-iceblue:spire.doc:11.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following commands to your project's **build.gradle**:

```
maven{url'https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
compile group:'e-iceblue',name:'spire.doc',version:'11.5.5'
```

If you're using gradle version 7+, use **implementation** instead of **compile**.

Here is an example:
[image]